# Class diagram created through ObjectedAid is empty when opened in another PC?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, objectaid

I have drawn a Class Diagram using eclipse plug-in objectaid and shared to my friend. He was not able to open it though he install objectaid.

Answer (score 0):

Did he have also classes used in the diagram? I believe you need them as well.